# How to re-use a private IP in a VPC with DigitalOcean?

Tags: digital-ocean, vpc

I have a VPC with several Droplets. They communicate with each other via private IPs. One of them needs to be replaced. I'd like to bring up a new Droplet using the same private IP of the one that will be replaced and then remove the old one.

Is this possible to do or will I need to go into all the other Droplets and re-wire them to communicate to the new one using a different private IP from the old one?

Comment: have you looked into floating ips? It might be hard to retrofit into your current situation but going forward it will address your problem.

Comment: @user3504575 I thought floating ips are public?

Comment: I think you are correct, they are public IPs. I still think you could maybe use them anyway in combination with the firewall for public internet protection, as droplets always have external IPs assigned to them anyway? What needs to be verified is that using the floating IP does not count towards your egress quota.